# Hadoop Pig: Extract all substrings matching a given regular expression

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I am parsing some data of the form:

```
(['L123', 'L234', 'L1', 'L253764'])
(['L23', 'L2'])
(['L5'])
...
```

where the phrases inside the parens, including the brackets, are encoded as a single chararray.

I want to extract just the L+(digits) tags to obtain tuples of the form:

```
((L123, L234, L1, L253764))
((L23, L2))
((L5))
```

I have tried using REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL using the regular expression '(L\d+)', but it only seems to extract a single tag per line, which is useless to me. Is there a way to create tuples in the way I have described above?

Comment: That's actually right, it should works if you use the FIND_ALL/EXTRACT_ALL define.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for FIND_ALL, but it sounds like what I'm looking for. can you point me in the right direction? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If order does not matter, then this will work:

```
-- foo is the tuple, and bar is the name of the chararray
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOKENIZE(foo.bar, ',') AS values: {T: (value: chararray)} ; 
C = FOREACH B {
    clean_values = FOREACH values GENERATE  
                   REGEX_EXTRACT(value, '(L[0-9]+)', 1) AS clean_value: chararray ; 
    GENERATE clean_values ;
}
```

The schema and output are:

```
C: {clean_values: {T: (clean_value: chararray)}}
({(L123),(L234),(L1),(L253764)})
({(L23),(L2)})
({(L5)})
```

Generally, if you don't know how many elements the array will have then a bag will be better.

Comment: I'm new to pig. Can you explain to me what the T: is for inside of the bag?

Comment: Bags are unordered sets of tuples.  In this case clean_values contains n tuples called T, where T contains just clean_value, a string.